# Navigation Drawer: отступ элементов меню и кастомизация с шаблона

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой в боковом меню, создал проект в Android studio 2.1.1 c боковым меню. Теперь удалил оттуда стандартные значки и названия пунктов меню встали впритык к левой части Navigation Drawer'а. Теперь я захотел сдвинуть текст пунктов меню к центру, но не смог.
Пытался задать стиль

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:itemPadding">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Потом

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

и ещё

```
<style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Последний вариант может и помог бы, но вот только он сдвигает меню полностью, с nav_header_main'ом.

Ещё пытался в strings в названия пунктов меню добавлять пробелы, но система не позволяет вставить и отобразить больше 1 или 2 пробелов перед текстом. Так же там пытался добавлять символы, чтоб пробелы системой не срезались. Так вот, прошу помочь с этим, как лучше сделать? Можно ли отцентровать или сдвинуть текст в боковом меню, используя проектный Navigation Drawer?

**Обновил_№1**

Мне нужно вот так

[image: боковое меню]

А у меня пока что вот так

[image: моё боковое меню]

(P.S. 1я картинка - от айфона, 2я - моя от сони)

**Не знаю, как отцентровать текст, как на картинке1, как добавить dimens и как менять цвет выбранного меню с каждой dimens сверху и снизу.**

**andreich** дал примерную наводку

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/design_menu_item_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/design_navigation_icon_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/design_menu_item_action_area_stub"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/design_menu_item_action_area"
    android:layout="@layout/design_menu_item_action_area"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Но игра с gravity не пошла =), текст не отцентровался, только с layout_marginLeft подвинуть смог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно создать лэйаут с названием `design_navigation_menu_item.xml` а в нем уже сделать такую разметку и настраивать стили как угодно. Главное сохранить название файла, id вьюхи в разметке и тип, должен быть `CheckedTextView` или его потомки. и все будет ок

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/design_menu_item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/design_navigation_icon_padding"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</merge>
```

По сути этот лэйаут лежит в библиотеке support либы, но при меже ресурсов будет использован данный лэаут.

Возможности кастомизации элементов, доступные из коробки

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_icon_tint"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/blue_gray_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer">
```

Чтобы добавить разделетели между пунктами, надо в файле, где описано меню, элементы обернуть в группы. Между группами появятся разделители

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/navGroup1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navMain"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:title="@string/home" />
</group>
```

Comment: у вас в коде блок ViewStub отсутствует. Посмотрите обновлённый вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: ну стаб да, опустил, надо играться с этими занчениями 
`android:gravity="center_vertical|start"`

Comment: а dividers в боковом меню и их цвета выделения тоже в этом же файлике надо расписывать? Впервые с этим файлом работаю, даже не знаю, за что блок стаба отвечает, но знаю, что без него вылетает

Comment: цвета выделения можно менять через настройку NavigationView

Comment: Обновил ответ с примером